# TSE_TO_STS application

Tags: traminer

I have 12 categorical sequence in TSE format. In the help page of this function tmax is specified as 12 based on the sequence data example used. How would I change this value if the maximum time length is 292 for one sequence and smaller than 292 for other sequences. Assume one of the sequence ends at time 25. using tmax=292, any state after 25 will use the same state till 292 which is wrong I believe. I would like to stop the sequence at time 25 and fill anything else on the right side with void.

Comment: I encourage you to give a small running example with say TSE data for two sequences and describing what you expect. We could then possibly show you how to proceed.

Comment: Here is the same example provided in help page but on a subset. 
data(actcal.tse)
subset<-actcal.tse[c(2:5,7:9),]
events <- c("PartTime", "NoActivity", "FullTime", "LowPartTime")

## States defined by last occurred event (forgetting all previous events).
stm <- seqe2stm(events, dropList=list("PartTime"=events[-1],
                                      NoActivity=events[-2], FullTime=events[-3],
                                      LowPartTime=events[-4]))

mysts <- TSE_to_STS(subset, id=1, timestamp=2, event=3,
                    stm=stm, tmin=1, tmax=12, firstState="None")
mysts

Comment: Here is the output. > mysts
           a1          a2          a3          a4          a5          a6          a7          a8          a9
2  NoActivity  NoActivity  NoActivity  NoActivity    FullTime    FullTime    FullTime    FullTime    FullTime
4 LowPartTime LowPartTime LowPartTime LowPartTime LowPartTime LowPartTime LowPartTime LowPartTime LowPartTime
       a10      a11      a12
2 FullTime FullTime FullTime
4 PartTime PartTime PartTime

Comment: We observe that for the first sequence FullTime state continue until a12, even in the TSE sequence Fulltime state is up to time 8.

Comment: Please edit your question with the examples in a readable form (using the appropriate formatting tools).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TSE_to_STS` is a function provided by the `TraMineRextras` package. It converts time stamped event sequences into state sequences. The resulting state sequences are in STS form, i.e., organized in a table with each sequence in a different row and the states in successive columns. `tmax`is used to determine the number of columns of this table. Therefore, it should be fixed to the maximal state sequence length.

To end a sequence at time 25 for example, you need to insert an end of sequence event at time 25. `TSE_to_STS` cannot guess when the sequence ends.

============ example

Below I illustrate how to proceed using the `actcal.tse` data that ships with `TraMineR`. I consider the data for ids 2 and 4  and assume id 2 was observed up to the 8th month and id 4 up to the 10th month.

```
data(actcal.tse)

## Consider the data for id 2 and 4 and  
## insert "endobs" event to indicate end of observation

subset <- rbind(actcal.tse[2:4,], data.frame(id=2,time=8,event="endobs"), 
                actcal.tse[7:9,], data.frame(id=4,time=10,event="endobs"))
subset
##    id time       event
## 2   2    0  NoActivity
## 3   2    4       Start
## 4   2    4    FullTime
## 1   2    8      endobs
## 7   4    0 LowPartTime
## 8   4    9    Increase
## 9   4    9    PartTime
## 11  4   10      endobs


## Define list of events of interest
events <- c("PartTime", "NoActivity", "FullTime", "LowPartTime", "endobs")
## Dropping all previous events
stm <- seqe2stm(events, dropList=list(PartTime=events[-1], NoActivity=events[-2], 
                FullTime=events[-3], LowPartTime=events[-4], endobs=events[-5]))
mysts <- TSE_to_STS(subset, id=1, timestamp=2, event=3,
                stm=stm, tmin=1, tmax=12, firstState="None")

## replacing "endobs" with NAs
mysts[mysts=="endobs"] <- NA
seq <- seqdef(mysts)
seqiplot(seq)
```

We see the different length of the two resulting state sequences in the plot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to keep different length sequence after the conversion to STS. If not, does it make sense to have a sequence of length 25 stretch to the maximal state sequence length (292 in this case)? Does it affect the state analysis afterwards such as plotting the sequences.

Comment: You can ignore the end of some sequences after the conversion if you want. However, as already mentioned in my answer, you have to indicate where you want the sequence to end. The last event (e.g. FullTime) indicates when a FullTime spell starts, but we don't know when this spell ends.

Comment: I have added an example to the answer

Comment: Thanks. That is very helpful.